# how to run multiple lambda function locally with docker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have multiple lambda python functions. Which is related to each other. Suppose I have a main lambda function. from that main lambda function, I have to go to different lambda functions based on the condition.

I have dockerized the main lambda function like below.

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10-x86_64

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}


# Install the specified packages
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy function code
COPY check_engine_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "check_engine_function.handler" ]
```

Lambda . check_engine_function.py

```
def handler(event, context):

    if json_data.get('tts_engine') == 'google':
        lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName=google_tts_lambda,
            InvocationType='Event',  # Asynchronous invocation
            Payload=json.dumps(json_data)
        )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('TTS processing initiated.')
    }
```

In this lambda function I have invoke an another lambda function.
Q1: How can I do this in my local PC using docker?

Q2: Do I have to create dockerfile for each lambda? Or can I use one dockerfile for all lambda and create the image and push it to the amazon ECR ?

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function (`google_tts_lambda`) is defined only by a python file (let's say `google_tts_lambda.py`) and a function (let's say `handler`).

Your code can then become:

```
if json_data.get('tts_engine') == 'google':
    if is_on_aws():
        lambda_client.invoke(
            FunctionName=google_tts_lambda,
            InvocationType='Event',  # Asynchronous invocation
            Payload=json.dumps(json_data)
        )
    else:
        import google_tts_lambda
        google_tts_lambda.handler(json.dumps(json_data))
```

This is a synchronous call for the example. You can use whatever is relevant to you (threading, multiprocess, background tasks if you are using fastapi) to get the asynchronous variant.

`is_on_aws()` can be defined in multiple ways, for instance checking if the `AWS_EXECUTION_ENV` environment variable exists, if you are only interested in lambdas.

Edit: I missed Q2. You can definitely use the same docker image. When you define a docker lambda, you can override `CMD`. This is [the doc to do it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/DockerImageCode.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.from_ecr) for cdk.